# How to loop through grid in d-dimensional ball

Tags: arrays

I have a grid (distance between nodes equal to 1) in the d-dimensional space. Now I want to loop through all grid-points which lie inside a d-dimensional ball (center at origin) with radius r. Of course I can loop through all grid points in the d-dimensional box with side-length 2r and check if they lie in the ball. However, particularly for large d, this will be a waste of resources (most grid points in the box don't lie inside the ball).

Comment: This is more of PnC. Imagine in d dimensions you have xd planes(x1, x2, x3... xd). Say, Coordinates of a point will be represented by(x1, x2, x3... xd). Now for your condition, distance from origin(dfo) =sqrt(sum(x1^2+x2^2+x3^2+....+xd^2))<=Radius. Begin with x1=x2=... xd=0. Increment xd by one, check condition. Continue this until dfo<=R. Now decrement xd by 1 and increment x(d-1) by 1. This will lead to a pattern and all nodes shall be traversed.

Comment: I like the idea. If you formulate as an answer, I would accept it. (what is PnC?)

Answer (score 0):

You can slightly improve the search in the hyper-cube [-r, r] in all d dimensions by reducing the size in the remaining hyper-plane. The rationale is that the remaining radius of the remaining hyperplane, when you at a particuliar coordinate is defined by:

```
new_radius = sqrt(old_radius^2 - current_coordinate^2)
```

You could use a recursive algorithm here in pseudo code

```
define function loop(dim, radius)    # will return a list of lists
    let l be the empty list
    loop for coord=0; coord<radius; coord = coord + 1
        newr = sqrt(old_radius^2 - coord^2)
        if dim is 1
            then append singleton list [coord] to l
        else
            for any list l1 in loop(dim-1, nr)
                append [coord] + l1 to l
        return l
```

This algo only processes positive coordinates, but it could be easily extended to process negative coordinates too by processing -x in addition to x when x is not null.

Comment: Are we entirely sure the above answer is correct? It fails when the dimension is > 3 in my implementation.